# How to see if multiple columns match different conditions and return text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to return a "u" if the cell to the left is in column I on my other tab AND if the cell underneath is in column F on the other tab. How would I go about this please?

So far I have in cell f7:  =IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(F8,Table!I:I,1,0)<>"","u",0),"")
but I need to also look in Table!F:F  to see if the date from the cell underneath is in it.

EXAMPLE

---

Here is my data in tab 1:

[image]

Here is what I'm looking to do in tab 2:

[image]

Comment: Use [AND](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9)

Comment: Hi Thanks for this, I have changed my formula, however, it is just returning the "u" if either of the statements are true, even though I'm using the AND(). I'm wondering if VLOOKUP is the best formula to use, perhaps I should use something else? I want to: look down my table (in I:I) until I find the first criteria if it's there, and then have a look across my table in F:F, and see if that matches another criteria (from my cell underneath). Maybe I should be using INDEX and MATCH? I'm not sure if this would work. I've never had to use a formula like this before. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly this formula should provide what you are looking for.

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(VLOOKUP(F8,Table!I:I,1,0)=F8,VLOOKUP(F9,Table!F:F,1,0)=F9),"u",0),"")
```

Using the AND() function requires both tests to be TRUE in order for the evaluations to be TRUE. An OR() allows both to be checked but returns TRUE if either is TRUE. So using the AND() checks both conditions and returns "u" in your IF statement only if both are TRUE.

I changed the logical criteria to equals just to be sure the values match.

Hi Becca,

It seems the part that I missed in the first attempt was the across. I think the vlookup is your easiest way to do this, but you may have to rearrange your columns. If you cut the column I:I on the table tab, and highlight column F:F right click and insert cut cells this will line the data up better for the vlookup. Now if you use the below formula you can compare across.

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(F8,Table!F:G,2,0)=F9,"u",0),"")
```

What this does is it finds the look up value and returns the value from the other column. Then it compares the returned value to the value in the cell underneath. If they match you get a "u" and if not, you get a "0". If the lookup is an error, you receive a blank.

[image]

[image]

Ok let's try this. A $ turns a relative reference into an absolute reference. The following looks up the name in column "A" and returns the date in column "B". It then compares that date to the value of row 10 of the current column. If it is drug across columns it will update to that column. If you wish to lock the column and unlock the row simply move the $ to before the "B" for the "B10" reference.

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($A2,Table!$A:$B,2,FALSE)=B$10,"U",0),"")
```

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

If you only care that the date is in the list below you could use an HLOOKUP.

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($A2,Table!$A:$B,2,FALSE)=HLOOKUP($B2,$10:$10,1,FALSE),"U",0),"")
```

Then you will have to use an index match however, this will not work on Excel 2019 or older. You will most likely need to use Excel 365. It will work best if you are always checking against the same reference (say B10), but you can drag it across.

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Table!$B:$B,MATCH($A2&B$10,Table!$A:$A&Table!$B:$B,0))=B$10,"u",0),"")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your formula solves the issue? Also check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to correctly format posts.

Comment: Hi Thanks for this, I have changed my formula, however, it is just returning the "u" if either of the statements are true, even though I'm using the AND(). I'm wondering if VLOOKUP is the best formula to use, perhaps I should use something else?

I want to: look down my table (in I:I) until I find the first criteria if it's there, and then have a look across my table in F:F, and see if that matches another criteria (from my cell underneath). Maybe I should be using INDEX and MATCH? I'm not sure if this would work. I've never had to use a formula like this before. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I have recreated what you have demonstrated but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for. I've updated the original question with some snippets to show exactly what it is I'm trying to do. I would appreciate any more help! Thanks, Becca :)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time, however, this isn't going to work as 'bob' or 'jane' might be in the data table on tab 1 multiple times. It is only returning the first lookup value, so only ever returning the first date available.

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much! This worked and so did using the countifs method! Thanks so much for your time and determination to get to the bottom of this! Much appreciated - Becca :)